# Is there a pattern to the occurrences of "reply to the argument for the contrary" section in Aquinas's  ℎ?

Tags: thomas-aquinas, summa-theologica

### The Anomaly

The other day when I was [answering a question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/89764/10672) using Thomas Aquinas's [Summa Theologica](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eafreddos/summa-translation/TOC.htm) (Notre Dame Prof. Alfred J. Freddoso's translation) I came across a new type of "Reply to Objection" in [II-II q.83 a.14](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eafreddos/summa-translation/Part%202-2/st2-2-ques83.pdf) called

> "**Reply to the argument for the contrary**"

The New Advent website version is not consistent.  Sometimes, the "On the contrary" is prefixed with another "Objection".  For example, in [Article 14](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/3083.htm#article14), the "On the contrary" is labeled

> "**Objection 4. On the contrary**"

and the reply is titled

> "Reply to Objection 4".

But sometimes the New Advent website simply adds another "Reply to Objection" with no corresponding "Objection", since the "On the contrary" *itself* is the objection.  For example in [I-II q.26 a.3](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/2026.htm#article3) ([Notre Dame version here](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eafreddos/summa-translation/Part%201-2/st1-2-ques26.pdf)), we have

> On the contrary

and

> Reply to Objection 4

I found other examples in

- **I-II q.11 a.2** (Whether to enjoy belongs to the rational creature alone, or also to irrational animals?): [ND website](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eafreddos/summa-translation/Part%201-2/st1-2-ques11.pdf) vs. [New Advent](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/2011.htm#article2)
- **II-II q.136 a.5** (Is patience the same as longanimity): [ND website](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eafreddos/summa-translation/Part%202-2/st2-2-ques136.pdf) vs. [New Advent](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/3136.htm#article5)

Using Google search on the query `"Reply to the argument for the contrary" site:www.nd.edu` yields [9 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Reply+to+the+argument+for+the+contrary%22+site%3Awww.nd.edu), but there are maybe more since this search is dependent on how uniform the labeling of the section is in Prof. Alfred J. Freddoso's translation (hosted in the ND website).

### The Question

What is the meaning of this rare occurrence?  Can we infer that St. Thomas does not have a definitive answer for the question?  Or does it point to something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "anomaly" seems to be when St. Thomas refutes or commentates on a *sed contra*.

In [II-II q. 83 a. 14](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS083.html#SSQ83A14THEP1), for example, he refers to a *sed contra* as the fourth objection:

> [II-II q. 83 a. 14 s.c.](https://www.corpusthomisticum.org/sth3082.html#42579):
> *Sed contra, videtur quod* [But against (the thesis), it seems that…]…

> [II-II q. 83 a. 14 ad 4](https://www.corpusthomisticum.org/sth3082.html#42584):
> *Ad quartum* [i.e., "to the *sed contra*"] *dicendum quod* [roughly, "I say that…"].

Usually, *sed contra*s are arguments from authority and he doesn't refute them.

---

St. Thomas doesn't number his objections in his original Latin, nor does he use the term "objection" there. The format is:

> *Videtur quod* [It seems that] …
>
> *Præterea* [furthermore], *videtur quod*…
>
> *Præterea*, …
>
> *Præterea*, …
>
> etc.
>
> *Sed contra* [On the contrary], …
>
> *Ad primum* [As to the first (objection)], …
>
> *Ad secundum* [second] …
>
> *Ad tertium* [third] …
>
> etc.

Comment: So what you are saying: since usually Aquinas doesn't refute *sed contra* from authority, Aquinas uses the "Reply to the argument for the contrary [the *sed contra*]" section **as a commentary** instead of the usual **argument against** an objection?  If that is so, why do you preface your answer with `The "anomaly" seems to be when St. Thomas refutes a *sed contra*.`  Shouldn't your answer be `The "anomaly" seems to be when St. Thomas **commented on** a *sed contra*.` ?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple "_usually Aquinas doesn't refute_ sed contra _from authority_." I said a _sed contra_ is usually an argument from authority. II-II q. 83 a. 14 s.c. is an argument from authority (from King David's Psalm in that case), but II-II q. 83 a. 14 ad 4 is not an argument from authority.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Adding the Latin original is very helpful.

Comment: This is a good answer, but "ad quartum" does not mean "to the *sed contra*."  It means, "to the fourth."  Freddoso translated it as "Reply to the argument for the contrary," and Shapcote translated it as "Reply to Objection 4."  Shapcote's translation is more literal.  In any case, Geremia identifies the key point that Aquinas' objections are not numbered.

...The other thing to note is that "sed contra" is equivocal, and Aquinas sometimes uses it as an objection from the contrary extreme, rather than as a contrary to the primary objection.

Comment: @zippy2006 _"ad quartum" does not mean "to the sed contra."_ Not generally, but in II-II q. 83 a. 14 it does.